# Exim DKIM Error: DKIM: signing failed (RC -101) no matter what private key I try

Tags: exim, dkim, rsa, private-key, domainkeys

I have this problem with Exim. DKIM fails on signing outgoing mails.

This is the /var/log/exim4/mainlog output (Debian Squeeze):

```
2012-08-02 17:11:33 1Sx1k5-0004Tk-9D <= me@my_domain.com U=me P=local S=399
2012-08-02 17:11:33 1Sx1k5-0004Tk-9D DKIM: signing failed (RC -101)
2012-08-02 17:11:33 1Sx1k5-0004Tk-9D => somebody@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.77.27] X=TLS1.0:RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1:16 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=mx.google.com"
```

The version of Exim running is: 
Exim version 4.72 
Berkeley DB: Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
Support for: crypteq iconv() IPv6 GnuTLS move_frozen_messages DKIM

As I've readed [here](http://mikepultz.com/2010/02/using-dkim-in-exim/#comment-2468):

> Hey Jon,
>   The error: “DKIM: signing failed (RC -101)” 
>   is the error code PDKIM_ERR_RSA_PRIVKEY (from src/pdkim/pdkim.h)
>
> ```
> /* Function success / error codes */
> #define PDKIM_OK 0
> #define PDKIM_FAIL -1
> #define PDKIM_ERR_OOM -100
> #define PDKIM_ERR_RSA_PRIVKEY -101
> #define PDKIM_ERR_RSA_SIGNING -102
> #define PDKIM_ERR_LONG_LINE -103
> #define PDKIM_ERR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL -104
> ```
>
> and is only returned in one place – in src/pdkim/pdkim.c
>
> ```
> /* Perform private key operation */ 
> if(rsa_parse_key(&rsa, (unsigned char *)sig->rsa_privkey,
> strlen(sig->rsa_privkey), NULL, 0) != 0) {
> return PDKIM_ERR_RSA_PRIVKEY;
> }
> ```
>
> So it looks like there is a problem parsing
>   the RSA key that you generated for Exim. This could be because the key
>   generation failed, or because exim doesn’t have access to the file
>   (file permissions). I would start by trying to re-generate your
>   certificates.

So the problem is in the private key.

I've tried generating different keys but no matter what private key I use, Exim still logging: DKIM: signing failed (RC -101).

I've tried:

```
# openssl genrsa -out dkim.private.key 768
```

then

```
# openssl genrsa -out dkim.private.key 1024
```

then

```
# openssl genrsa -out private.key 768
```

or

```
# openssl genrsa -out private.key 1024
```

even I've tried this [DKIM Key Generation Wizard](http://www.socketlabs.com/services/dkwiz)
but the error is still there.

This is the Exim config section for DKIM (from /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template):

```
remote_smtp:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp

  dkim_domain = my_domain.com
  dkim_selector = dkim
  dkim_private_key = private.key
  dkim_canon = relaxed
```

the keys I'm using are in /etc/exim4 to avoid permissions issues

Has anyone any idea? How can I solve this and get my outgoing mails signed

Comment: Silly question, is the private key readable by the exim user?  Putting it into /etc/exim4 doesn't magically make it readable.  Run something like the following: `sudo su -l -s /bin/bash -c 'cat /etc/exim4/private.key' exim`

Comment: It has the same owner as exim4.conf.template and Exim can read this configuration.
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 76500 Aug  2 17:55 exim4.conf.template
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   887 Aug  2 17:45 private.key

Could you please suggest an appropriate owner for Exim to read this file?

Comment: One possibility is that your permissions are too liberal, and need to be more restrictive? There's a number of instances where software checks that a private key is only readable by the owner (ie `chmod 400`) and refuses to use it if it's world-readable. Try turning off group and world permissions for the key.

Comment: @lturri.cf, It's not clear how you installed exim on your system.  Is there a "mail" user, or perhaps an "exim" user?  Who owns the /etc/exim4 directory?

Comment: @cjc the /etc/exim4 directory is owned by root:root. There is a mail "mail" user and a "Debian-exim" user. Debian-exim owns the /var/log/exim4 directory so I've changed the private.key owner to match "Debian-exim" and set permissions to 600, but still fail =(

Comment: Silly question: do you need to specify the full path to the private.key in the dkim_private_key setting?

Comment: @cjc thank you! I've solved it by setting the absolute path:
dkim_private_key = /absolute/path/to/private.key

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue with exim and dkim by setting the absolute path to my private key (thanks to @cjc):

The final DKIM configuration section goes like this:

```
remote_smtp:
  debug_print = "T: remote_smtp for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = smtp

  dkim_domain = my_domain.com
  dkim_selector = dkim
  dkim_private_key = /absolute/path/to/my/private.key
  dkim_canon = relaxed
```

Thats all!
Then just restarted Exim